# Not sure it would work when server list is fetched from a file

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose you have 100 computers in a LAN (a list of host names in a file in each line), and each computer has its own disk, and these computers are shared by several people. You can assume that the disks are mounted at a fixed point "/local" on each computer. You have to print two things:  a) Top 10 disk users across the network. b) Top 10 users in terms of total login time(in last 24 hrs)across all the computers in the LAN.

My Script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while read -r host 
do 
ssh -n $HOST `uname -a` 
`du -s * | sort -nr | head -n10`>"top_10_du.txt" 
`cat top_10_du.txt` 
`last | sort -nr | head -10`>"last_users.txt" 
`cat last_users.txt` 
done<server_list.txt
```

Comment: So do you have a question about this script? You don't need all those backticks btw, just doing `cat last_users.txt` will work fine.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Comment: `$host` != `$HOST`

Comment: you are sending output to a file to `cat` it in the next line, you can avoid that

Comment: Yes!! I was not able to test this script as i do not have servers. so, not sure if it would work as per given requirement